# не запускается Unity 3D

Tags: unity3d

Устанавливал через Hub.

на пути нет русских символов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

о пк:

- AMD FX 4300
- AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series

Comment: вы переустанавливали виндовс перед этим?

Comment: @Andrey да , виндовс новая

Comment: скорее всего у вас проблемы с драйверами видеокарты. Или не стоят или стоит их обновить

Comment: @Andrey обновил , самые актуальные стоят

Comment: у вас только одна видеокарта?

Comment: @Andrey да , всего одна

Comment: у меня больше нету идей. Была похожая проблема но она решилась обновлением драйверов

Comment: @Andrey может ли моя видеокарта не тянуть unity ?)

Comment: думаю что это вряд ли возможно

Comment: `DirectX` поставили?

Comment: @KingPeas нет , но игры работают (со стрима )